# can vb.net show the VolumeLabel of the Harddrive in Usercontrol?

Tags: vb.net

i try to show the list of harddrive from a computer system
but i found that i can't show it in the "Label" user control

i try it on `messagebox.show()` , this work properly
can anyone please point out what is the problem of my code?
or just only certain object in vb.net can show the string of volumelabel?
thank you

this is the code of mine:

```
private sub getDriveInfo

    for each driveList as DriveInfo in DriveInfo.GetDrives()

        dim _label as label = new label
        dim localStorage as new list(of string)

        'localStorage.Add(driveList.VolumeLabel) this doesn't works
        '_label.Text = driveList.VolumeLabel) this doesn't work as well
        'label.Location = new point(10,10)
        'Messagebox.Show(driveList.VolumeLabel) this works properly
    Next

end sub
```

and one more bug i found, if i call this method, my user control will disappear,

for an example

```
private sub new()

getDriveInfo() 'if i don't call this method, my user control at below is visible

Dim _textbox as textbox = new textbox

with _textbox

    .location = new point(50,50)
    .font = new font("arial", 10, regular) 'after the method is called, this disappear

end with

controls.add(_textbox)
end sub
```

Comment: Both `Label` and `TextBox` was created with default `.Location = (0, 0)` - so `TextBox` was simply placed over `Label`. In code for label you need add label to the `Controls` collection to be displayed.

Comment: sorry for the unclear code,

Comment: both of the object's location was place if different coordinate, it this case it still doesn't show the volumelabel in my label, the volume label won't get into my list of ' localStorage'

Answer (score 0):

In both examples you must need to set the Parent of the control:

```
_label.Location = New Point(10, 10)
_label.Parent = Me
```

...Or add it to a control collection of the Form/Control (eg. your `UserControl.Controls()` collection):

```
_label.Location = New Point(10, 10)
Me.Controls.Add(_label)
```

Also be aware that a default `Label` control has an `AutoSize` property enabled, this means it will not show as multiline/all the drive labels until you disable the autosize and resize the label to fit the text. Same for a TextBox, you need to enable the `TextBox.MultiLine` property and resize the control

An example:

```
Friend LabelDrives As New Label()

Private Sub BuildAndShowDriveLabel()

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each drive As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        ' Not ready drives will throw an exception so we do a sanity check.  
        ' (eg. DVD-ROM drives that are loading a disc)
        If (drive.IsReady) Then 
            sb.AppendLine(drive.VolumeLabel)
        End If
    Next drive

    With Me.LabelDrives
        .SuspendLayout()
        .Parent = Me
        .Text = sb.ToString()
        .AutoSize = False
        .Size = New Size(TextRenderer.MeasureText(.Text, .Font))
        .Location = New Point(10, 10)
        .ResumeLayout(False)
    End With

End Sub
```